# Prevent 'nothing' being copied to clipboard

Tags: big-sur, copy-paste

I'm using Big Sur 11.5 on an M1 Mac.

Sometimes, in text editors, when trying to cut and paste with cmd-x, I seem to accidentally do some button combination (maybe cmd-z, i'm not sure) that deletes the selected text, then wipes the content of the clipboard, so that when I go to paste it in the new place nothing happens.

I think what's happening is that the text is being deleted, by accident, then the cmd-x happens, and it replaces the contents of the clipboard with an empty string.

If there was some way to configure the clipboard software with a rule like "Don't update the clipboard contents if the incoming string is empty" then that would help me out.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

**EDIT**:  I've noticed a detail about what's happening.  In the Atom and the Brackets text editors, they both have this behaviour:

**If you copy with nothing selected, it copies the whole of that line, including line ending, into the clipboard**

So, if I have a line like

foo

and I put the cursor in between the letters, with nothing selected, and copy, it copies "foo\r" into the clipboard.

This same behavior is used if you do it on an empty line:  you get "\r" in the clipboard.

That actually explains some other things where it pasted the whole line instead of just the part i'd selected (or thought i had, i must have not selected anything).

So maybe that's the behaviour that I want to disable.

**EDIT 2**
I think this behaviour is specific to the Atom text editor and Brackets text editor, rather than a Macos thing.  Because it happened in the two first apps I tried I unconsciously assumed it was system-wide.

Comment: It doesn't update clipboard if you copy/cut an empty string - it beeps instead. Depending on your last cut source, try Ctrl/Y instead. that's a separate clipboard, used for search functions usually, if you don't invoke it intentionally.

Comment: In most apps, you can see that Cut and Copy are greyed out when nothing is selected. Maybe get a clipboard manager app that stores the last 10 items.

Comment: @Tetsujin that's not what I see, see my edit.

Comment: I now think that this behaviour is specific to Atom and Brackets rather than being system-wide.  It doesn't do this while editing an email in Chrome, for example.